# Multi-line regex replace tags inside tags?

Tags: html, regex, lookbehind, negative-lookbehind

I want to replace single-line `b`/`h2`/`h3`/`h4`/`h5` tags inside `blockquote` tags, with `h6` tags.

So I want this:

```
^<[b|h[2-5]]>([^\.]+)</[b|h[2-5]]>$
```

to be replaced with this:

```
<h6>\1</h6>
```

but only if it's within a `blockquote` tag, which is on different lines. I'm thinking the solution must involve a lookbehind for a closing `blockquote` tag AND a negative-lookbehind for an opening `blockquote`, but I'm not sure how to implement this.

Comment: Character classes are not groups.

Comment: And if this is for arbitrary document structure, I'm afraid you might be barking up the wrong tree not using an XML parser to achieve there result. [Rant](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions are extremely bad for parsing arbitrary HTML, as many things can go wrong.

That being said: [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/iK4yH4/1) may get you started.

This doesn't deal properly with edge cases.

```
<div><b>This thing</div></b>
```

will not parse properly.

If you know your input is well-formed and doesn't have too deep of nesting (a `<b>` within a `<h2>` within something else, for example), then it may work. But to parse HTML, you really need a DOM parser.

Now, this does not handle the "between `blockquote` tag" requirement, but with Javascript (if this is what you're using), this isn't a very simple task [example](https://regex101.com/r/iK4yH4/2). You have to essentially run the same process over and over to get all of the elements converted to `h6`.

If you were to use jQuery instead, you could do it much more safely: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ofqs6dm1/)